# ASP.NET Core Razor Read related data into table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to create a asp.net core 2.1 razor website that will load two tables on the one page. Below i have defined my classes ItemMasters and DealMasters. ItemMasters stores items of clothing and DealMasters stores deals on them items. DealMasters stores the relevant ItemID with DealItemId

im trying to have the getItem Page to show the deals table but only the entires where the DealItemId matches the ID of the item on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> im trying to have the getItem Page to show the deals table but only the entires where the DealItemId matches the ID of the item on the page

It is because the you use `FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.DealItemID == this.id)`,try to use:

```
DealsMasters = await _context.DealsMasters.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hi Yiyi, thanks for your reply! I tried adding that to my code but was given this error  "'List<DealsMasters>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'List<DealsMasters>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" Any reply would be much helpful

Comment: I have updated my answer,you can try to use `await _context.DealsMasters.ToListAsync();`.